# Create class instance in python from list as attributes

Tags: python

So I have an object:

```
class Particle(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, vx, vy, ax, ay):
        self._x = int(x)
        self._y = int(y)
        self._vx = int(vx)
        self._vy = int(vy)
        self._ax = int(ax)
        self._ay = int(ay)
        # ...
```

I want to create an instance of that object from a list of numbers. How would I do that? `Particle(list)` doesn't work because it only inputs a list, not each value in the list. Thanks so much, I am sure there is a very obvious answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precede your list name by a star:

```
def foo(a, b, c):
    print(a, b, c)

a = [1,2,3]
foo(*a)
# 1 2 3
```

The star unpacks the list, which gives 3 separate values.

Comment: Thanks so much! I knew there was a simple way to do what i wanted!

Answer (score 2):

What you need is called "unpacking argument lists". 
Here's an example taken from the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
>>> range(3, 6)             # normal call with separate arguments
[3, 4, 5]
>>> args = [3, 6]
>>> range(*args)            # call with arguments unpacked from a list
[3, 4, 5]
```